# Are there any contemporary English words derived from same root as Euterpe & Terpsichore?

Tags: etymology

*Euterpe* & *Terpsichore* both contain the same etymological word root:

> **Euterpe**
>   muse of music, from Greek Euterpe, literally "well-pleasing," from eu "well" (see eu-) + ***terpein "to delight, please" (see Terpsichore).*** "

and

> **Terpsichore**
>   the muse of the dance, Greek Terpsikhore, literally "enjoyment of dance," from ***terpein "to delight" (from PIE root terp- "to satisfy;"***) + khoros "dance, chorus"

Does the Greek word root, **terpein**, or the parent PIE root terp- survive in any contemporary English word (not directly related to the two muses themselves)?

Comment: You can try looking through http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=words-matching-pattern&sword=*terp*&page=23, although there are lots of false positives from word boundaries.

Comment: Of course my first thought was the sweet-smelling ***turpentine***, and I was especially excited about the idea after reading [the first entry here](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=gcide&Query=terpene), but unfortunately, as it turns out, the Greek root of that word is actually τερέβινθος, *terebinthe*, having a "B", as opposed to the "P" found in εὖ+τέρπειν. In turn, τερέβινθος is derived from an earlier Pelasgian word, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistacia_terebinthus#History).

Comment: My first thought is the "degenerate" answer: *Terpsichorean*.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thrive), *thrive* is from this root. (The OED does not go back beyond North Germanic for this, and Pokorny doesn't mention it).

> ***thrive***: from Middle English *thriven*, from Old Norse *þrífa* (“to *seize, grasp, take hold, prosper*”), from Proto-Germanic **þrībaną* (“to *seize, prosper*”), from Proto-Indo-European **trep-*, ****terp-*** (“to *satisfy, enjoy*”).

Unfortunately, Wiktionary's policy on referencing only covers examples, not etymology, so there is no reference for the origin. The OED doesn't mention the "prosper" meaning for the Old Norse word,

Comment: This is interesting! Can you quote the relevant parts of the Wiktionary entry here, with a link back to the page? Also might be interesting to chase through Wiktionary's own references on this subject, to get back to the original source.

Comment: Done. No sources, as I mention.

Comment: And English *thrift*.

Comment: _Thrift_ is derived from _thrive_ within English, I think. Like _height_ and _weight_.

Answer (score 2):

The *[torpēre](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=torpeo)* entry from Charlton T. Lewis, Charles Short, *A Latin Dictionary* begins:

> *torpĕo, ēre*, v. n. Sanscr. root *tarp-*, to sate; Gr. *τέρπω*
>
> I. to be stiff, numb, motionless, inactive, torpid, sluggish, etc. [...]

This is also mentioned at the Wiktionary entry for [*torpeo*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/torpeo), French and English version. This would give *torpor*, for example.
The [English version](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/torpeo) goes on to suggest a link to PIE **ster* (“stiff”), which projects into Old English as *steorfan* ("to die"), modern English *starve*.

Found *en route* starting from the Czech [trpět](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/trp%C4%9Bt) ("to suffer"), by the way.

**Edit.**
[**(s)terp-*](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fpiet&text_number=2571&root=config#) entry in *[The tower of Babel](http://starling.rinet.ru/)* by Sergei Starostin et al. mentions **terp-* as possibly the same root.

Comment: *Torpedo* also comes from this root (being the Roman name of an electric fish, resembling a cylinder, whose shock apparently made the victims numb and lethargic). Whether this is too indirect to qualify for OPs question I know not.

Comment: Well, there you go. A real etymology for *stiff* = "corpse" without reference to rigor.